# Is it possible to use diff and patch tools to achieve the desired result?

Tags: unix, diff, patch

I have a dir D-1.0.3 and D-1.0.5 with files A and B (and other subdirectories and files within D-x.x.x) with the following version tree of file A and B (alike in terms of versioning, also the other subdirs and files)

1.0.3 - 1.0.5

|

1.0.3.1 (head)

I would like to apply changes from 1.0.5 to 1.0.3.1 using diff and patch tool as i don't have access to git or svn tools associated to the files.

Is this possible using the unified diff format (or whatever)?How can I achieve that if possible (the command set i need to execute)?

I have checked that there is no adds, deletes or rename of the filename associated to the changes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use `diff` to capture the difference between two directory trees.  There are a few pitfalls:

- in case you have *new* files (not in the older tree), you should use the `-N` option
- if directories were added or removed, `diff` will not tell you about the files within those directories.  I use a Perl script `makepatch` (an older version than on CPAN) which works around that problem.

For the simple case (no added/removed directories), you would use

```
diff -Naur olddirectory newdirectory >myfile.diff
```

and I would apply it in the top-level of the directory to be patched,

```
patch -p1 < myfile.diff
```

to eliminate problems due to the actual name of that directory.  The `-p1` option discards the name of the top-level directory.

To recap, assuming that these are the names of your directories, all subdirectories of the current directory:

```
diff -Naur 1.0.3 - 1.0.5 >mydiff.diff
cd 1.0.3.1 && patch -p1 <mydiff.diff
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt, but if you noticed, i have 3 directories not just olddirectory and newdirectory
there are plenty of tutorials telling me how to diff 2 directories which are directly related.

the relationship between the 3 directories is as per the tree above, can you adjust the commands to suite the requirements?
thanks